# Merge multiple base64 images into one

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

If I have multiple base64 strings that are images (one string = one image). Is there a way to combine them and decode to a single image file? i.e. from multiple base64 strings, merge and output a single image file.

I'm not sure how I would approach this using Pillow (or if I even need it).

Further clarification:

1. The source images are TIFFs that are encoded into base64
2. When I say "merge", I mean turning multiple images into a multi-page image like you see in a multi-page PDF

Comment: How are those images encoded and stored? What is their format? What libraries/modules can you use? How would you like to 'merge' those images? Too many questions...

Comment: @zwer They're TIFF images encoded into base64 strings. They're stored in a list in a JSON object. I don't really have any restrictions on libraries to use. I mean "merge" as in creating a multi-page file like you would expect in a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I dug through the Pillow documentation (v5.3) and found something that seems to work. Basically, there are two phases to this:

1. Save encoded base64 strings as TIF
2. Append them together and save to disk

Example using Python 3.7:

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import base64

base64_images = ["asdfasdg...", "asdfsdafas..."]
image_files = []

for base64_string in base64_images:
    buffer = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_string))
    image_file = Image.open(buffer)
    image_files.append(image_file)

combined_image = images_files[0].save(
    'output.tiff', 
    save_all=True, 
    append_images=image_files[1:]
    )
```

In the above code, I first create PIL Image objects from a bytes buffers in order to do this whole thing in-memory but you can probably use `.save()` and create a bunch of tempfiles instead if I/O isn't a concern.

Once I have all the PIL Image objects, I choose the first image (assuming they were in desired order in `base64_images` list) and append the rest of the images with `append_images` flag. The resulting image has all the frames in one output file.

I assume this pattern is extensible to any image format that supports the `save_all` and `append_images` keyword arguments. The Pillow documentation should let you know if it is supported.